# bind event in a directive doesn't work if the directive is in a ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs

It seems everyone is asleep on the angularjs google group :)

Here's my problem:

I have a select in a directive, and I want to bind a function to the 'change' event of that select.
My problem is that when I use this directive in an ng-repeat loop, the bind to the event doesn't work anymore (why ??).

**EDIT:**
In my real case, there are three or more `<select>`, created and populated with data from a json file.

Here is a simplified version of the directive, and I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qDFbyKmTapYu0QhP2KXt) as well.

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('mySelect', function() {

  var baseElt = angular.element('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>');

  return {

    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(topElement) {

      var elt = baseElt.clone();

      topElement.append(elt);

      return function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {

        elt.bind('change', function() {
          alert("change !");
        });

      };

    }
  }; 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need

```
app.directive('mySelect', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>',
        link : function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.bind('change', function() {
                console.log("change !");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uw6PZ/)

Comment: This works, but in my real case my directive has 3 selects, populated with data coming from a json file. That's why I use a compile function , and why I bind to `elt` and not to `element` in my linking function, to know what select changed.

Comment: HAHA yeah it works too, but with jQuery and I can't use it. The doc about angular.elements says "find() - Limited to lookups by tag name".

In this http://jsfiddle.net/uw6PZ/4/ I removed jQuery and use `element.find('select')` for the bind. The binding works (although it doesn't solve my problem with many selects). So why the binding works if I use find, and not if I use the direct reference created by angular.element() ? Isn't it the same underlying HTML object inside the two ?

Comment: @y__b__y as you know the compile function only runs once, so the `elt` element in all the link functions will refer the same select element instead of referring the select inside the looped control

Comment: @y__b__y what is the IE support level you are looking for

Comment: @y__b__y if you are looking for IE>=8 then look at [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) to search the element by class, see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uw6PZ/5/

Comment: Oh nothing related with IE compatibility, I just don't want to use only one JS library (angular).
My mistake was to believe that the compile function was run once per display of the directive. It's true if they're added 'by hand' to the DOM (ie in the HTML source code), but not true if the directive is in a ng-repeat loop. Thanks for pointing that.